# swift firestore get value in field

Tags: ios

How can I check the value in the field and achieve different purposes.

[As shown in the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTd8O.png), if the VIP value is 0, it will display "Unable to go"

Check that the VIP value is 1 and go to View

what should i do to achieve

This is my current code

```
 let UID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            let docRef = db.collection("Users").document(UID!)
            
            docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    
                    
                    self.showMsg(message: "no")
                    
                }else{
                    let array = document!.get("vip") as! String
                    switch array {
                    case "0":
                        self.showMsg(message: "0")
                    case "1":
                        self.showMsg(message: "1")
                        
                    default:
                        print("the other city")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let UID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
let db = Firestore.firestore()
let docRef = db.collection("Users").document(UID!)

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                if error == error {
                    print ("Error Occurs")
                } else {
                    let array = document.data["vip"] as! String
                    switch array {
                    case "0":
                        self.showMsg(message: "0")
                    case "1":
                        self.showMsg(message: "1")
                        
                    default:
                        print("the other city")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Hope, The above answer will satisfy your need.